# Making a menu responsive, problems with the code (css/php)

Tags: php, css

I took over a web site, which I'm making responsive. It's a "learning php/css" project for me, since I'm not a coder (besides basic html/css)

I'm trying to get the menu responsive, and it worked somehow. However the menu icon doesn't show up when resizing the window. Any helpful hints?

below is the PHP resp CSS

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul class="tabbed">
        <li<?php if ( is_home() ) : ?> class="current_page_item"<?php endif; ?>><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>">Hem</a></li>
        <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=1'); ?>
        <li class="navigation"></li>
        <li class="menuicon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction">&#9776;</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

CSS-file

```
ul.tabbed {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333; 
}
ul.tabbed li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
ul.tabbed a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.tabbed li.menuicon {
    display: none;
}
#navigation-wrapper {}
#navigation-wrapper-2 {
    background: url('img/wrapper-2.png') repeat-y center top;
}
#navigation {
    background: url('img/navigation.png') repeat-x left top;
    min-height: 46px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
#navigation a {
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding: 7px 12px 8px;
    margin: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#navigation a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}
#navigation li.current_page_item a, #navigation li.current_page_parent a {
    color: #000;
}
#navigation li.current_page_item a {
    background: #fdf9f0;
}
#navigation li.current_page_parent a {
    background: #fdf9f0;
}
```

Comment: do use any CSS media queries? , also have you added the correct viewport meta tag for a mobile device?

Comment: just so you know `ul.tabbed li.menuicon { display: none; }` this is why its not displaying. You need to add a media query that will change this to `display: block/inline-block.....etc` depending on what you need.

Comment: Thanks for quick replies!, I have media queries:  

     ul.tabbed li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
     ul.tabbed li.menuicon {
     float: right;
     display: inline-block;
   }

    ul.tabbed.responsive {position: relative;}
    ul.tabbed.responsive li.menuicon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    }
    ul.tabbed.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
    }
    ul.tabbed.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    }

Comment: thats still normal css what media are you enclosing these in like:
`@media only screen
  and (min-device-width: 320px)
  and (max-device-width: 568px)   {
  ul.tabbed li.menuicon {
  display: inline-block !important;
  }
}`

Comment: Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {...}

Comment: do you use the meta viewport tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`